# Why do Monte-Carlo methods converge quadratically?

Tags: monte-carlo, statistics

I'm reading Sutton's *[Reinforcemant Learning: An Introduction](http://incompleteideas.net/book/RLbook2020.pdf)*, and here's a part from page 93 of this book:

> In this case each return is an independent, identically distributed estimate of $v_\pi(s)$ with
> finite variance. By the law of large numbers the sequence of averages of these estimates
> converges to their expected value. Each average is itself an unbiased estimate, and the
> standard deviation of its error falls as $1/\sqrt{n}$, where $n$ is the number of returns averaged. Every-visit MC is less straightforward, but its estimates also converge quadratically to $v_\pi(s)$

I'm aware that $Var(\bar{X}_n)=\dfrac{\sigma^2}{n}$ and thus "the
standard deviation of its error falls as $\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$". But why does he say that every-visit MC **also** (which implies that fisrt-MC does too) converge **quadratically**?

Doesn't the word "quadratic" mean "square"?

Comment: If your idea is that MC converges "squarerootedly" (i.e. as $n^{-\frac{1}{2}}$) and not "quadratically" (as $n^{-2}$), I agree with you. It seems like sloppy language on the author's part.

Comment: @noob2 Thx for your reply. That's exactly what I mean. It's just that this book is very popular and as far as I've googled, no one has ever questioned about this, which seems unbelievable to me and makes me wondering if there's something I'm missing.

Comment: Just a wild guess: might this have to do with the different modes of convergence: in distribution, in probability, almost surely, in mean square (*quadratically*?)?

Comment: @RichardHardy Thx for your reply. I've been thinking about it. But I think MSE(\bar{X})=Var(\bar{X}), considering that \bar(X) is an unbiased estimate, which means that even "MSE-wise" speaking, it converges linearly (n^-1).

Comment: @zzl, I am talking about modes of convergence, not speed of convergence.